# How to extract certain text in a text python regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've got 3 lines of html code here:
I want to extract the hightlighted areas, each of the colours in a group.

```
<TD STYLE="border-bottom>2,000,000</TD><TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt; text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD><TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD><TD STYLE="text-align: right">1,333,000</TD><TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD COLSPAN="2">&nbsp;</TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
```

I tried:

```
(?<=</TD>)<TD.*>(&nbsp;<)/TD>
```

only matches the rear part, but miss the former.

This is what I expected:
[image: ![hightlighted Values in groups]

I get these highlighted values in a list:

of 1st line:

```
<TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt; text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt">&nbsp;</TD>
```

of 2nd line:

```
<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
```

of 3rd line:

```
<TD COLSPAN="2">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
```

Eventually:

```
['<TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt; text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD>&nbsp;</TD>','<TD COLSPAN="2">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD>&nbsp;</TD>']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<[\w\":;\-= ]*>[^\d]*?</TD>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9lwXCs/2)

To get a list, you could do this:

```
import re
pattern = r"(<[\w\":;\-= ]*>[^\d]*?</TD>)"
test_str = ("<TD STYLE=\"border-bottom>2,000,000</TD><TD STYLE=\"padding-bottom: 4pt; text-align: left\">&nbsp;</TD><TD STYLE=\"padding-bottom: 4pt\">&nbsp;</TD>\n"
    "<TD STYLE=\"text-align: left\">&nbsp;</TD><TD STYLE=\"text-align: right\">1,333,000</TD><TD STYLE=\"text-align: left\">&nbsp;</TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD>\n"
    "<TD COLSPAN=\"2\">&nbsp;</TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>")
matches = re.finditer(pattern, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
[match.group() for match in matches]
```

Output:

```
##  ['<TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt; text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD STYLE="padding-bottom: 4pt">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD STYLE="text-align: left">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD>&nbsp;</TD>','<TD COLSPAN="2">&nbsp;</TD>','<TD>&nbsp;</TD>']
```